# Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string when comparing datetimes

Tags: php, datetime

I have this string:

```
$actualTimePreformatted="16:46:00";
```

And I need mysql to select tu_id number **294**, as that ID has a range of times containing this time:

[image: Table image]

To do this I have passed the given time string to a time type data, and then selected the turn by comparing it's content:

```
$actualTime= DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $actualTimePreformatted);

$timeMatchingTurns=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM turn_conf WHERE
        (tu_mon_1_s >= $actualTime AND tu_mon_1_e <= $actualTime) OR
        (tu_mon_2_s >= $actualTime AND tu_mon_2_e <= $actualTime) OR
        (tu_mon_3_s >= $actualTime AND tu_mon_3_e <= $actualTime)"); 

$finalResult=mysql_fetch_array($timeMatchingTurns);

$turn_id=$finalResult['tu_id'];
```

This, instead of storing on $turn_id the id **294**, gives me the error "Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string".

Comment: `$actualTime` is an (DateTIme) object, and you're dumping it inside a _STRING_ in the query. There's the error.

Comment: It somewhat goes without saying - you should use prepared statements. Now that that's out of the way - use $actualTimePreformatted in your SQL instead of $actualTime.

Comment: @DamienPirsy the fact is that "tu_mon_1_s" and all the rest of fields like it, are TIME fields, not strings. If I compare the STRING info with TIME fields, without formattinf $actualTime, it gives me "mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given". I thought that error was due to the difference between the nature of both data...

Comment: @JonSturdevant I tried that but got only the "mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given" error. Thought it was because not having formatted $actualTimePreformatted –

Comment: @Biomehanika Put single quotes around the variable in your SQL. ie. `"...WHERE (tu_mon_1_s >= '$actualTime' ..."`

Comment: Thank you Jon, now theres no error but "$turn_id=$finalResult['tu_id'];" does not print anything.. Ill keep on checking this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change this line:

```
$actualTime= DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $actualTimePreformatted);
```

By the follow:

```
$actualTimeObj = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $actualTimePreformatted);
$actualTime = $actualTimeObj->format('H:i:s');
```

You are using an Object as an String.

Besides, the query should have single quotes around the variable, like:

```
$timeMatchingTurns=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM turn_conf WHERE
        (tu_mon_1_s >= '$actualTime' AND tu_mon_1_e <= '$actualTime') OR
        (tu_mon_2_s >= '$actualTime' AND tu_mon_2_e <= '$actualTime') OR
        (tu_mon_3_s >= '$actualTime' AND tu_mon_3_e <= '$actualTime')");
```

Comment: Hi Leticia. I have done this, and it gives me the same error than when I use directly $actualTimePreformatted in the SQL instead of $actualTime: "mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given"

Comment: Ok, after applying your edit, error is no longer appearing but "$turn_id=$finalResult['tu_id'];" does not print anything.. shouldnt it be stored there?

Comment: mysql_fetch_array return a non associative array, try with $finalResult[0];

Comment: Or you should use mysql_fetch_assoc() instead of mysql_fetch_array()

Comment: I think there must be some problem with the select, maybe with the nature of the data compared... If I make this query, it results on 0 (and ID 294 should be selected, isnt it?): 
SELECT *
FROM turn_conf
WHERE (
tu_mon_1_s >= '17:13:00'
AND tu_mon_1_e <= '17:13:00'
)

Comment: Should be SELECT * FROM turn_conf WHERE ( tu_mon_1_s <= '17:13:00' AND tu_mon_1_e >= '17:13:00' )

Comment: Changing the <= by >=, and >= by <=